# How to pass a Kotlin KProperty to a function omiting the class qualifier?

Tags: kotlin, generics, reflection

I have the following code:

```
class generic<T> {
 fun <U> addProp(prop: Kproperty1<T,U>) {...}
}

class A(val i:Int)

val genericA=generic<A>()

genericA.add(A::i)
```

It is OK but I would prefer to omit the A qualifier and make the following call:

`genericA.add(::i)`

I think it would be possible by changing the add function signature because the compiler knows that it is a property of A (T generic parameter is A).
Do you know if there is any way? Maybe with reified parameters?

Comment: Pretty sure the compiler is not so sophisticated as to support things like that. KProperty is a reflection feature. Reflection features are not first class parts of the language syntax that are given privilege to specific help from the compiler for conciseness. Also in this case, that shortcut is not feasible because it wouldn't be able to distinguish member properties from extension properties.

Comment: Related thread: https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/2179935. I'm not entirely convinced by the conclusion there; I still think it might be possible to add this feature to the language.